# How do I import a file into my project folder using PyQt5's QFileDialog?

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to import a csv file into my Python project with PyQt5's QFileDialog.  All I need is for it to copy a file from one location and paste it in another yet I can't seem to figure it out.

```
    def open(self):
        home_dir = str(Path.home())
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', home_dir)

        # if file selected import into folder
        if fname[0]:
            print(fname)
            with open(fname, 'r') as fobj, open('Data/Inventory.csv', 'wb') as f:
                data = fobj.read()
                df = pd.read_csv(data)
                f.write(df)
```

So far this is all I have.  I had a version before that created a blank file in the desired directory but that's obviously not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out so I thought I'd share what I found.

```
    def open(self):
        home_dir = str(Path.home())
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', home_dir)

        # if file selected import into folder
        if fname[0]:
            shutil.copyfile(fname[0], 'Data\Inventory.csv')
```

That's literally it.

Comment: Also consider [`QFile.copy()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#copy).